# iPhone- Send JSON Object to PHP server in POST

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest, json

I would like to send my contact list with all numbers for each numbers.

I'm trying to send a JSON Object (with all my data) to a PHP file and to decode with the `json_decode` function.

Is it possible to use JSON to send to a server by POST in HTTPrequest

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use JSON to send to a server by POST in HTTPrequest

JSON is just text.  You can send *text* via POST, right?  Then you can send JSON.

Comment: Do I have to convert my Json object in String?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify to create a String from a JavaScript Object.

E.g. JSON.stringify({field1:"a", field2:"b"})

I would use any library like jQuery to post JSON data to the server.

Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Charles said, JSON is a string. As long as it's part of a POST which you can retrieve on your server, it should be enough.

ASIHTTPRequest is a great library for handling POST data sent from the iPhone to your server. Here's an example on how to send a POST: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest

Here's a question related to encoding a NSString to JSON: [Send NSMutableArray as JSON using JSON-Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245191/send-nsmutablearray-as-json-using-json-framework)